# scrollregion in Canvas in Tkinter?

Tags: canvas, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

I wrote a program in Python. But I wonder if there might be shorter way of doing this. Especially about "Canvas", "Frame", "LabelFrame" and "Label", is there any other way to make "scrollregion" automatically (rather than I wrote, and if possible natural way in Tkinter)

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
dict = {}
Liste = ["bir","iki","üç","4",5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
a = 1

####### ekleme basi ##################################################
pencere = Tk()
pencere.geometry("{0}x{1}".format(100, 100))

labelFrame = LabelFrame(pencere, width = 100, height = 100)
labelFrame.pack(side="left",fill=BOTH)
canvas = Canvas(labelFrame,relief=SUNKEN)
#canvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,300,1000))    # halloldu =)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(labelFrame)
scrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side="right",fill=Y)
canvas.pack(side="left",expand=YES,fill=BOTH)

frame = Frame(canvas,width=100,height=100)
frame.pack(side="top",fill=BOTH)
canvas.create_window(0,0,window=frame, anchor="nw")
####### ekleme sonu ##################################################

bas = [0, 0, 0, 100]
for i in Liste:
    dict["a%s"%a] = Label(frame, text=i)    # "frame" ekledim
    dict["a%s"%a].grid(row=a)
    canvas["scrollregion"] = "%d %d %d %d" %(bas[0], bas[1], bas[2], bas[3])
    bas[3] += 16    # "scrollregion" i dinamik olarak arttir (degistirebilirsiniz)
    a += 1


mainloop()
```

Note: English is my second language and I don't know very well, so sorry.

Answer (score 8):

The typical way to set the scroll region is to set it to the bounding box of everything that is in the canvas, which can be retrieved with the `bbox` method, giving it the literal string `"all"`

```
canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: The question is: at what time do you get something from canvas.bbox("all"). If you call that too early, you only get wrong values.

Comment: In some cases, it's also necessary to call the root.update() before setting the scrollregion.