# My canvas keeps scrolling when I use my mouse wheel to scroll, but scrolls properly when I use the scrollbar in TkInter and Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When I use the scroll bar my canvas scrolls properly when I use the scroll bar instead of the mouse wheel. When I use the mouse wheel, it scrolls infinitely but when using the scroll bar it scrolls till the end of the canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image,ImageTk


OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path(r"C:\Users\scien\build\assets\frame0")

def submitform():
    pass

def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)


root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg="#c3ff84")
root.title("PIL App")
container = ttk.Frame(root)
canvas = tk.Canvas(container, height="700", width="1150", bg="#d6eccc")
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)

scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)

scrollwindow = canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

        
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

canvas.create_text(
    32.0,
    0.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="What is your job description?",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Consolas", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    32.0,
    177.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="Type in your full address here",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Consolas", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    33.0,
    531.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="What is the crime that was committed?",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Consolas", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    32.0,
    708.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="To which High Court are you filing this PIL?",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Consolas", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    32.0,
    1081.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="How did you find about this crime?",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Consolas", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    33.0,
    1258.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="What is the damage caused by the crime?",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Consolas", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    33.0,
    1630.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="Have any representations been made on \nthis topic before? ",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Consolas", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    32.0,
    1415.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="How did you find out about this crime? \nWhat is the source of information?",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Consolas", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    32.0,
    875.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="Write brief facts about the matter \non which this PIL is being filed",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Consolas", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    33.0,
    354.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="Who/What business are you filing this PIL against?",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Consolas", 36 * -1)
)    


entry_image_1 = tk.PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("entry_1.png"))
entry_bg_1 = canvas.create_image(
    455.0,
    113.0,
    image=entry_image_1)

entry1 = tk.Entry(canvas, bd= 2, relief="flat", width="45", font=('Consolas 24') )
canvas.create_window(455, 113, window= entry1)

entry_image_2 = tk.PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("entry_2.png"))
entry_bg_2 = canvas.create_image(
    456.0,
    290.0,
    image=entry_image_2
    
)
entry2 = tk.Entry(canvas, bd= 2, relief="flat", width="45", font=('Consolas 24') )
canvas.create_window(455, 290, window= entry2)

entry_image_3 = tk.PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("entry_3.png"))
entry_bg_3 = canvas.create_image(
    456.0,
    467.0,
    image=entry_image_3
)   
entry3 = tk.Entry(canvas, bd= 2, relief="flat", width="45", font=('Consolas 24') )
canvas.create_window(455, 467, window= entry3)

entry_image_4 = tk.PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("entry_4.png"))
entry_bg_4 = canvas.create_image(
    455.0,
    644.0,
    image=entry_image_4
)

entry4 = tk.Entry(canvas, bd= 2, relief="flat", width="45", font=('Consolas 24') )
canvas.create_window(455, 644, window= entry4)

entry_image_5 = tk.PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("entry_5.png"))
entry_bg_5 = canvas.create_image(
    456.0,
    821.0,
    image=entry_image_5
)

entry5 = tk.Entry(canvas, bd= 2, relief="flat", width="45", font=('Consolas 24') )
canvas.create_window(455, 821, window= entry5)

entry_image_6 = tk.PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("entry_6.png"))
entry_bg_6 = canvas.create_image(
    455.0,
    998.0,
    image=entry_image_6
)

entry6 = tk.Entry(canvas, bd= 2, relief="flat", width="45", font=('Consolas 24') )
canvas.create_window(455, 998, window= entry6)

entry_image_7 = tk.PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("entry_7.png"))
entry_bg_7 = canvas.create_image(
    455.0,
    1194.0,
    image=entry_image_7
)

entry7 = tk.Entry(canvas, bd= 2, relief="flat", width="45", font=('Consolas 24') )
canvas.create_window(455, 1194, window= entry7)

entry_image_8 = tk.PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("entry_8.png"))
entry_bg_8 = canvas.create_image(
    456.0,
    1371.0,
    image=entry_image_8
)

entry8 = tk.Entry(canvas, bd= 2, relief="flat", width="45", font=('Consolas 24') )
canvas.create_window(455, 1371, window= entry8)

entry_image_9 = tk.PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("entry_9.png"))
entry_bg_9 = canvas.create_image(
    455.0,
    1548.0,
    image=entry_image_9
)

entry9 = tk.Entry(canvas, bd= 2, relief="flat", width="45", font=('Consolas 24') )
canvas.create_window(455, 1548, window= entry9)

entry_image_10 = tk.PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("entry_10.png"))
entry_bg_10 = canvas.create_image(
    455.0,
    1757.0,
    image=entry_image_10
)

entry10 = tk.Entry(canvas, bd= 2, relief="flat", width="45", font=('Consolas 24') )
canvas.create_window(455, 1757, window= entry10)


submit = tk.Button(canvas, text="Submit", font=('Consolas 24'), command= submitform(), relief="flat", bg="white")
canvas.create_window(525, 1850, window= submit)

submit_imagesource = Image.open(relative_to_assets("submitbutton2.png"))

resize = submit_imagesource.resize((276,100), Image.ANTIALIAS)

submit_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize)

'''submit_images = canvas.create_image(
    525.0,
    1850.0,
    image=submit_image)'''

submit = tk.Button(canvas, text="Submit", font=('Consolas 24'),image= submit_image, command= submitform(), 
                   relief="flat", bg="white", borderwidth=0, activebackground="#d6eccc", background="#d6eccc" )
canvas.create_window(580, 1850, window= submit)

imageup = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(relative_to_assets("uptop.png")))

label1 = tk.Label(root, text="PIL App", font=("Consolas", 26), bg="#c3ff84")
label1.pack(side="top")

def _on_mousewheel(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
    
canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)

container.pack()
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True,)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

root.resizable(False, False)

root.mainloop()
```

I tried to scroll using mouse wheel but it scrolls infinitely, how do I make it scroll just till the end of the canvas.

Comment: You have not set the `scrollregion` option of the canvas.

Comment: I'm on Windows and i can't see any problem.

Comment: @acw1668 point out used `canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all"))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scrollregion in Canvas in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860062/scrollregion-in-canvas-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems fine but the fact that you didn't define the `scrollregion` of the canvas. For example check your line:

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(container, height="700", width="1150", bg="#d6eccc")
```

Try to use the argument `scrollregion = (x1, y1, x2, y2)`. For example:

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(container, height="700", width="1150", bg="#d6eccc", scrollregion=(0, 0, root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height()))
```

`root.winfo_width()` and `root.winfo_height()` are respectivly the width and the height of your root window so that the scroll region is defined is the whole window only.